# Laravel Jetstream breaks when no logged in user exist

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-jetstream

I am developing an application. I have chosen to use Jetstream with LiveWire. I installed it to my application. I can create accounts, log in, log out. But when I try to open the homepage, I get error:

> Attempt to read property "name" on null

at line `/resources/views/navigation-menu.blade.php : 85`

That line is

```
{{ Auth::user()->name }}
```

The error is caused by there is no logged in user. But this should not be. Any user could visit the home page.

I commented that line. Then it gives the same error at `/resources/views/navigation-menu.blade .php : 164`

```
164 <x-responsive-nav-link href="{{ route('profile.show') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('profile.show')">
165    {{ __('Profile') }}
166</x-responsive-nav-link>
```

I am at the beginning. There is no significant modification on any .php file. So there is no need to change anywhere in the view, I think. Because they are ready made codes.

What I have got in the `/routes/web.php` is the following:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::middleware([
    'auth:sanctum',
    config('jetstream.auth_session'),
    'verified',
])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');
});
```

Comment: did you remove the auth middleware from this route?

Comment: just surround the part that needs a user to be logged in with `@if( Auth::user() )......@endif`

Comment: @krisgjika I have not changed anything yet. It is as how it was installed.

Comment: {{ Auth::user()?->name ?? "Guest" }}